# Help with XML-RPC server

Tags: php, codeigniter, xml-rpc

I'm now trying to create a xml-rpc server with the CodeIgniter Framework.

```
<?php
$this->load->library('xmlrpc');
$this->load->library('xmlrpcs');

$config['functions']['weblogUpdates.ping'] = array('function' => 'weblogUpdates.ping');
$config['functions']['ping'] = array('function' => 'weblogUpdates.ping');
$config['functions']['weblogUpdates'] = array('function' => 'weblogUpdates.ping');
$config['object'] = $this;

$this->xmlrpcs->serve();
?>
```

But the problem I have is when Wordpress is trying to ping my file. I can't figure out what I should have as function in the $config['functions'][HERE];

Anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [the codeigniter user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/xmlrpc.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, found the problem, I'm so dumb.
Had a beta-server up running which I had set Wordpress to ping, and forgot to change the address when I got the new server :$